# Writing data to new database - collation question

Tags: sql-server, migration, collation

We will be changing the collation of our databases in a few months. I am setting up an environment, to test the new collation with my application.  I have created a database with our new collation and want to write data into the new database.

Database1: `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`
Database2: `Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS_WS`

If I run the following query:

```
INSERT INTO Database2.table1
SELECT * FROM Database1.table1
```

...will SQL use the collation of `Database2` or `Database1` to write the data?

Both databases are on SQL Server 2012.

The collation for Database2 is `Latin1_General_CP1_AS_WS`

Comment: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS_WS are you sure this a valid collation?

Comment: The collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS_WS` doesn't seem to be a valid collation. The nearest one is `Latin1_General_CI_AS_WS` (fixed question). While the question and answer supplied by Kin are a bit wide, the reason given in the introduction states that the collation has no impact on the data stored _Collations in SQL Server provide sorting rules, case, and accent sensitivity properties for your data. Collations that are used with character data types such as char and varchar dictate the code page and corresponding characters that can be represented for that data type._

Comment: An answer to this question stating why the collation has (no) impact on a data migration would benefit the community.(Reopen request)